# Компоненты GUI и объект события

Tags: java

Как заставить компонент GUI(кнопку, например) передать в метод класса-слушателя параметр?

Говоря проще, мне это надо для получения информации о том компоненте, который произвел событие. 
Аналогичный вопрос насчёт метода `getSourse ():`

```
actionPerformed( ActionEvent a) { if(getSourse () == button) { //Код } }
```

Скомпилируется ли этот код?

Comment: Вам нужна информация о том, на какую кнопку нажали и какое событие при этом нажатии произошло?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо заставлять, обработчик принимает событие, которое уже содержит эту информацию:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSourse() == button) {
        //Код
    }
}
```